# How can I restrict an Interface to be implemented by only a generic type

Tags: c#, oop

I've been in an interview recently where interviewer asked me this question-

> How to write an interface so that it restricts or enforces to be implemented
>   by only a generic type or prevent providing implementation?

Could somebody please answer this question with some code sample or provide any reference of the exactly same question with sample snippets for understanding.
Is it possible? If YES then how and If NO then why?

Comment: What was meant by `generic` type?

Comment: You cant restrict the usage of an interface to a generic class

Comment: any generic class @Michal

Comment: Interfaces define a set of public properties and methods that the implemented classes must,eh... implement. By itself it can be generic. It can't enforce the implemented classes to be generic as well. Also, surely, interfaces cannot throw exceptions.

Comment: No, you can't. Why? Because neither the CLR nor the C# compiler provide this kind of feature. Simple as that. Was the interview in English, or is your question just translated incorrectly? (Since you say "_I saw many questions were asked on this topic_", i suspect a mistranslation here)

Comment: however you can constrain a generic type to an interface

Comment: This is a great time to visit [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to restrict who implements your interface.

The only restriction you can give is for the interface to be generic

- e.g. `public interface IInterface<T> { }`

And you can also restrict the generic `T` of the interface to some type.

- e.g. `public interface IInterface<T> where T : GenericConstraint { }`

This `GenericConstraint` restriction can also be the following:

- struct
- class
- unmanaged
- new()
- base class name
- interface name
- another generic type

For more info on the constraints available see [MS Docs - Constraints on type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

As [@Saruman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612975/saruman) has pointed out, it is highly recommended to read:

[MS Docs - Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

### RE: " where T " can be of any kind of class or I can enforce it be of some specific type? could you please provide some snippets on this?

If you use a specific class name:

> The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.

Therefore if I have the following classes:

- `public class GenericConstraint { }`
- `public class NewGenericConstraint : GenericConstraint{ }`

I could provide both `GenericConstraint` and `NewGenericConstraint` to `IInterface<T> where T : GenericConstraint` because both of those are or derive from `GenericConstraint`.

Therefore the following classes would be valid:

- `public class Subject : IInterface<GenericConstraint> { }`
- `public class Subject : IInterface<NewGenericConstraint> { }`
- `public class Subject<T> : IInterface<T> where T : GenericConstraint { }`
- `public class Subject<T> : IInterface<T> where T : NewGenericConstraint { }`

The `GenericConstraint` cannot be a sealed-class because if `GenericConstraint` was sealed, e.g.:

- `public sealed class GenericConstraint { }`

You wouldn't be able to inherit from it, and the following would fail to compile:

- `public class NewGenericConstraint : GenericConstraint { }`

Therefore, it would be pointless to provide a generic parameter of which constraint is a sealed class. Therefore the compiler enforces you to constrain a generic type to a **non-sealed class**

Comment: or SomeClass<T> : Where T : ISomeInterface. however the jury is out on what the wording actually means

Comment: " where T " can be of any kind of class or I can enforce it be of some specific type? could you please provide some snippets on this?

Comment: @LogicalDesk you can only enforce it to be at a minimum a specific type, but unless that type is sealed, it can be something that inherits that type

Comment: Actually I didn't get the comment completely as I'm not aware of that much OOPs. could you please give me some example code so that I can understand properly.

Comment: Actually, I would not use the name `SomeClass`, but `GenericConstraint`, which is that it actually is. Other then that, good answer. +1.